# No Order Summary on Checkout Page (Magento 2.3)

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, magento2.3, checkout-page

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.1, the order summary on the checkout page is not showing at all.

[image]

No error in the console and I have also checked the logs, nothing seems to be helping.

Current PHP Version: 7.1

Upgraded to Magento 2.3.1 from 2.1.3

Comment: Have you use custom theme or custom extension for this?

Comment: Yes, there is a custom theme, but most of the components are driven from the core. Also, there was no problem with the page before the upgrade.

Comment: Does your theme compitible with latest magento 2.3.1?

Comment: Yes, it is. Everything else seems working fine as expected.

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I checked the Knockout flow and found a problem with one of the conditions we have in the Order Summary section.

The file that I override with our theme is `Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js`

The function that was creating a problem for us was `isFullMode()`. This function was returning false that's why the summary is not visible at all. We modified the code of this function to make sure it returns true to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What was your solution to this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/301663/56248